# Bloco "If <condition> Then" não faz sentido

Tags: if, condição, vbscript

Estou encarregado de manter uma aplicação em VBScript, porém minhas principais linguagens de programação são Java (7+), JavaScript e PHP (5.4+).

Durante a revisão do código para poder refatorar as horripilantes linhas *macarrônicas* que encontrei, me deparei com a seguinte linha, que, confesso eu, jamais havia visto em qualquer outro código.

```
If 1 = 2 And IsNull(NO_ARQUIVO) And IC_ATIVO Then
```

Eu gostaria de ajuda para entender o que esse trecho de código está fazendo.

O que `If 1 = 2` quer dizer?

Existe alguma nuance da linguagem VBScript que corrobora com a referida linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é igual em qualquer linguagem, está verificando se 1 é igual a 2, o que obviamente é falso e fará o `If` ser falso já que as outras condições estão ligadas por um `And`. Então provavelmente foi uma forma da pessoa fazer não entrar nesse bloco sem apagar o código, típica gambiarra.

Comment: Qual a melhor maneira de corrigir essa atrocidade? `If Not IsNull(NO_ARQUIVO) And IC_ATIVO Then` é apropriado?

Comment: Não, isto passaria executar sob certas condições, a solução correta é apagando todo o bloco porque agora ele não é mais executado, nunca. Fora isso só perguntando para quem fez porque criou essa aberração.